# python process terminates with tmux

Tags: tmux

my python process terminates although it is using tmux. The steps I take:


1) ssh to 'user'

2) tmux

3) python3 'here goes process'

4) 'ctrl+b' and 'd'

5) exit ssh

6) log back to ssh

7) tmux attach -t [tmux session]

8) process is dead


Why is the process no longer alive?

Comment: You have checked your logs and the python process does not error out?

Comment: i'll have a look at it